# In Coldfusion / CFML, how do you format a long decimal number to a standard two number percentage?

Tags: coldfusion

In Coldfusion / CFML I need to convert 0.85035035035 to 85%. I looked at [numberFormat()](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=functions_m-r_08.html), but it's output looks like, "0.85". There doesn't seem to have a method to omit the leading "0.".

```
<cfset myNumber = 0.85035035035>
<cfoutput>
    #numberFormat(myNumber, "0.00")#%
</cfoutput>
```

Outputs: **0.85%**

Ideas? Do I need to trim the leading 2 characters in a second operation?

```
<cfset myNumber = 0.85035035035>
<cfset myPercent = numberFormat(myNumber, "0.00")>
<cfoutput>
    #right(myPercent, 2)# %
</cfoutput>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
<cfoutput>#Round(myNumber * 100)#%</cfoutput>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
 <cfset num = 0.85>
 <cfoutput>#NumberFormat(num * 100,"999")#%</cfoutput>
```